# Textbox: Mixed colors and data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, formatting

Dear stackoverflow community!

I tried to find a solution to my problem but I cannot find any.

**Problem:**

I have a multiline Textbox that binds to a string. Whenever I add something to the string, I would like to change the color of the **new part only**.

In the end it should should look like this:

[image: Textbox:]

(You get the idea)

Here is my Textbox so far:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="ChatTextBox" Text="{Binding MyStringProperty , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsReturn="True"                 
             IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

While searching for a solution I saw some examples using Inlines, but to me it looks that Inlines cannot be dynamic.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
     <TextBlock.Inlines>
         <Run Foreground="Blue" Text="The first line in the Textbox is blue"/>
         <Run Foreground="Green" Text="then I add this part and it is green"/>
         <Run Foreground="Orange" Text="and this part is orange" />
     </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

I do not necessarily have to bind to a string, if any other objects (or list) is needed, this wouldn't be a problem.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RichTextBox control and use Paragraph's and Run's, check this:

```
    <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Margin="10,128.08,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="The first line in the Textbox is blue" Foreground="Blue"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" Foreground="Brown"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="then I add this part and it is green" Foreground="Green"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="and this part is orange" Foreground="Orange"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as far as I see the code is still bound to the length of 3 lines in this case.
What if my text should grow to 10 lines?